# Azure AD B2C - Custom UI - Date picker validation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to fix this validation that appears for the date picker (date of birth, in this case), when I use Azure AD B2C custom UI. This validation appears right after I choose the day, instead of waiting for the user to submit the other fields.

Is there a way to only run this validation when the form is submitted?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [page version 1.2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout) has introduced a user input validation delay for improved user experience. Also look at `setting.inputVerificationDelayTimeInMilliseconds` [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata).

```xml
<ContentDefinitions>
  <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
  </ContentDefinition>
</ContentDefinitions>
```

Comment: it worked for other input fields in the same page. So the other text box wait a few seconds now, but the date picker still gives the error message right after you choose the day, before I have even time to choose the month and year.
     ` <ClaimType Id="extension_dob">
        <DataType>date</DataType>
        <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
        <!-- Use custom date range - from 1900-01-01 to Today -->
        <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
      </ClaimType>`
This is the definition of the date picker.

Comment: any other suggestion?